# Struts2 How to create a table by iterating a list such that each row has a radio button?

Tags: struts2, radio-button, html-table

I am trying to create a table to display some data using iterator over my list from action class. Each row has the properties of each object in the list.

```
<table class="TableA" cellpadding="5px" border="1">
<tr class="even">
    <th></th>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>Col2</th>
</tr>
<s:iterator value="objectList" status="obj">
    <tr
        class="<s:if test="#obj.odd == true ">odd</s:if><s:else>even</s:else>">
        <td></td>
        <td><s:property value="objId" /></td>
        <td><s:property value="objValue" /></td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

I need a radio button in first cell of every row so that a row can be selected for edition or deletion.
I know this can be done using `<input type="radio" ...>`. But I need to use struts2's radio tag. But problem using this tag is that it generates a row for every radio tag (see [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/struts-2-form-tags.html)).

Is it possible ? If yes then how ?

Comment: If I use <input type="radio" ...>, then is it possible to get the selected row's associated value in the action class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kaillash: 
if i understand your requirements completely all you mean to say that when page getting displayed with struts2 radio button struts2 is automatically creating a row for each radio button.

if this is the case than that is default struts2 functionality,struts2 operates on template theme and the default theme (xhtml) will automatically generate some HTML markup for each struts2 tag.

if you want struts2 tags not to generate any extra markup use the theme as simple.it can be done per tag basis something like this

```
<s:radio key="personBean.gender" list="genders" theme="simple" />
```

or you can also set theme on the page basis..
create struts2.properties file in the root and put the following entry

```
struts.ui.theme=simple
```

i hope this will help you

Answer (score 3):

I think the following syntax will be better for you as you want to select each row with radio button

```
<s:radio theme="simple" name="object_radio" list="#{objId:objId}"/>
```

This way you wont need the objId column too
This syntax will submit objId as the value of selected radio button.You can modify the syntax to change the display property of the radio button or make it blank

Answer (score 1):

anu, your answer helped me a lot.
Also this link was of great help for me:
http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/how-do-i-render-a-single-radio-button.html

What I needed was a table where two of the columns were radio buttons, but each column was an independent group. Furthermore I did not want to show the key as the label/value for each radio button, since that information was displayed in the other columns. My rows were built iterating over a hashmap, where the key of the hashmap was the radio button value.

```
<s:iterator value="myHashMap">
<tr>
  <td><s:radio name="selectedRadioValueFirstColumn"  list="#{key:''}"/></td>
  <td><s:radio  name="selectedRadioValueSecondColumn" list="#{key:''}"/></td>
<%--....... (my other columns) .... --%>
<tr>
```

So I am setting the option value as the key of the hashmap, and the selected value will be stored in the string property "selectedRadioValueFirstColumn" and "selectedRadioValueSecondColumn".